# Generate name for Named Pipe

Tags: windows, named-pipes

What is the "best way" to generate a name for a Windows named pipe so it will not conflict with other processes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a GUID.........

Answer (score 0):

You company name plus something, e.g. plus the process ID.